# I'm trying to make a roblox fps shooting game and my code for kills, deaths, and coins leaderboard isn't working, how do I fix it?

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm trying to make a roblox fps shooting game and my code for kills, deaths, and coins leaderboard isn't working, it's supposed to give 25 cash every kill, but somehow the cash ruined the entire leaderboard stats.

The code is supposed to give you a kill everytime you kill a player and a death everytime you die to a player, it is also supposed to give you 25 cash everytime you kill a player.

here is the code:

```
local Players = game.Players

local Template = Instance.new 'BoolValue'
Template.Name = 'leaderstats'

Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Kills"
Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Deaths"
Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Cash"


if tag ~= nil then
    local killer = tag.Value
    if killer ~= nil then

        local killerStats = killer:FindFirstChild("Leaderboard")

        if killerStats ~= nil then

            local killerCash = killerStats:FindFirstChild("Cash")

            killerCash.Value = killerCash.Value + 25
        end
    end
end

Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Player)
    wait(1)
    local Stats = Template:Clone()
    Stats.Parent = Player
    local Deaths = Stats.Deaths
    Player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(Character)
        Deaths.Value = Deaths.Value + 1
        local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChild "Humanoid"
        if Humanoid then
            Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
                for i, Child in pairs(Humanoid:GetChildren()) do
                    if Child:IsA('ObjectValue') and Child.Value and Child.Value:IsA('Player') then
                        local Killer = Child.Value
                        if Killer:FindFirstChild 'leaderstats' and Killer.leaderstats:FindFirstChild "Kills" then
                            local Kills = Killer.leaderstats.Kills
                            Kills.Value = Kills.Value + 1
                            
                            
                            end)
                        return
                    end
                end
            end)
        end
    end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some flaws in your code because the script does not know what tag stands for. You don't even know the tag code because you already have kill count working so just do the same for cash. And for death count you can just increase the Player "Deaths" value.

```lua
local Players = game.Players

-- create template
local Template = Instance.new('BoolValue')
Template.Name = 'leaderstats'

Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Kills"
Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Deaths"
Instance.new('IntValue', Template).Name = "Cash"


Players.PlayerAdded:connect(function(Player)
    wait(1)
    local Stats = Template:Clone()
    Stats.Parent = Player
    local Deaths = Stats.Deaths
    Player.CharacterAdded:connect(function(Character)
        Deaths.Value = Deaths.Value + 1
        local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChild( "Humanoid")
        if Humanoid then
            Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
                for i, Child in pairs(Humanoid:GetChildren()) do
                    if Child:IsA('ObjectValue') and Child.Value and Child.Value:IsA('Player') then
                        local Killer = Child.Value
                        if Killer:FindFirstChild ('leaderstats') and Killer.leaderstats:FindFirstChild("Kills") then
                            local Kills = Killer.leaderstats.Kills
                            Kills.Value = Kills.Value + 1
                            
                            -- here we know the killer so give them $25 cash 
                            local cash = Killer.leaderstats.Cash
                            cash.Value = cash.Value + 25
                            
                            -- To increase death count, we already know Player died so just increase his death count
                            Player.leaderstats.Deaths = Player.leaderstats.Deaths + 1
                        end
                        return
                    end
                end
            end)
        end
    end)
end)
```